# how insert the multiple checkbox values into database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

By this code i can able insert the checkbox values to database. But i need add one column in phpmyadmin and in that column i need store the values like, if i select 2 checkbox, i need store that ckeckbox values in one column in another column i need store for selected checkbox as YES and unselected values as NO. But see i want both column

here is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Home" id="pageHome" onChange="toggleVisibility('home');" /><label for="pageHome"> Home</label><img id="home" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden"/><br/>

<input name="checkbox[]" value="About_us" id="page_Aboutus" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('aboutus');"><label for="page_Aboutus"> About Us</label><img id="aboutus" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden" /><br/>

<input name="checkbox[]" value="Services" id="pageServices" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('services');"><label for="pageServices"> Services</label><img id="services" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden" /><br/>

<input name="checkbox[]" value="Products" id="pageProducts" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('products');"><label for="pageProducts"> Products</label><img id="products" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden"/><br/><br>

<input name="checkbox[]" value="Enquiry" id="pageEnquiry" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('enquiry');"><label for="pageEnquiry"> Enquiry</label><img id="enquiry" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden"/><br/><br>

<input name="checkbox[]" value="Contact_us" id="pageContact" type="checkbox" onChange="toggleVisibility('Contact');"><label for="pageContact">Contact Us</label><img id="Contact" src="images/icon-tick.png"  style="visibility:hidden" /><br/>
```

php code

```
$required_pages = implode(',', $_REQUEST['checkBox']);

$sql="insert into request_quote(customer_name,organisation,phone_num,email,country,state,city,zipcode,project_type,website_url,website_purpose,website_keyword,Competitors,sample_websites,no_of_updation,required_pages,additional_page,other_details) 
        values('$customer_name','$organisation','$phone_num','$email','$country','$state','$city','$zipcode','$project_type','$website_url','$website_purpose','$website_keyword','$Competitors','$sample_websites','$no_of_updation','$required_pages','$additional_page','$other_details')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please make your question into more than two sentences and one looong sentence. It is hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `value='YES'` attribute to each of your checkboxes.
Then make an array where you assume no checkbox has been checked. Because when we iterate later, only the checked checkboxes will be sent via `$_REQUEST`.

```
$checkBoxes['customer_name']="NO";
$checkBoxes['organisation']="NO";
$checkBoxes['phone_num']="NO";
$checkBoxes['email']="NO";
$checkBoxes['country']="NO";
$checkBoxes['state']="NO";
$checkBoxes['city']="NO";
$checkBoxes['zipcode']="NO";
$checkBoxes['project_type']="NO";
$checkBoxes['website_url']="NO";
$checkBoxes['website_purpose']="NO";
$checkBoxes['website_keyword']="NO";
$checkBoxes['Competitors']="NO";
$checkBoxes['sample_websites']="NO";
$checkBoxes['no_of_updation']="NO";
$checkBoxes['required_pages']="NO";
$checkBoxes['additional_page']="NO";
$checkBoxes['other_details']="NO";
// Only the checked checkboxes wil be itterated below.
// This will mean the $value would be YES no matter what.
// So I write it literal for SQL-Injection-security
foreach ($_REQUEST['checkbox'] as $checkboxName=>$value){
  $checkBoxes[$checkBoxName]="YES"; 
}
```

And in your SQL-Query, replace the variables with items from the array.
I.E.

```
$sql="insert into request_quote(customer_name) 
    values('".$checkBoxes['customer_name']."')";
```

---

### Security tip:

Also, directly inserting user input can be a huge security risk. Use `mysql_real_escape_string($value)` on all user-input-values you plan to use in a SQL-query.

---

You should look into $_POST. W3Schools will help you out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp.

Comment: how can i insert the loop values to database

Comment: Via the `$checkBoxes`-array. As I just added (right above the security tip). :)

Comment: You the $checkBoxes-array is the equivalent of $required_pages in your code.

Comment: but i need two columns in database. one column has the checkbox values other column has the "YES" or "no"

Comment: The checkbox **value** *is* YES or NO. The checkbox, **names**, however is set in the SQL query right after `INSERT INTO request_quote(`. I'm just to lazy to add all the fields :)

Answer (score -2):

You have to use 3 tables, and relationate each other

1. `table 1 -> customers (id, name, etc)`
2. `table 2 -> required_pages (id, name)` - here you will add your options from checkbox (Home, About_us, etc)
3. `table 3 -> customers_required_pages (id, customer_id, required_page_id)`

When saving data, you will have to save sequentialy:

1. Your customer:

   ```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (field1, field2, fieldn...)"
   $qry = mysql_query($sql);
   ```
2. Retrieve your customer Id:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS customerId";
   $qry = mysql_query($sql);
   $customerId = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
   ```
3. Save the relationship between customers and required_pages

   ```
   <?php
   foreach ($_REQUEST['checkBox'] as $oneCheckbox => $checkboxValue) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO customers_required_pages (customer_id, required_page_id) VALUES ({$customerId['customerId']}, '{$checkboxValue}')"; 
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. When retrieving your data, you will select values from table2 using left join with table3, this way you will be able to know wich values where or not selected from the checkbox list

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT rp.id, rp.name, IF(crp.customer_id IS NULL, 'NO', 'YES') AS checked FROM required_pages rp LEFT JOIN customers_required_pages crp ON rp.id = crp.required_page_id";
   ```

As an extra, consider use MySQLi or PDO instead of mysql as your database library, since the use of mysql lib has been discouraged

Answer (score -5):

I was having the problem to store the multiple checkbox into the mysql table, but now it's working fine with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require("config.php");
    ?>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $fname  =   $_POST['fname'];
        $lname  =   $_POST['lname'];
        $gender =   $_POST['gender'];
        $hobbies    =   implode(",",$_POST['hobbies']);
        echo $hobbies;
        $country    =   $_POST['country'];
    //  echo $hobbies;
        //foreach($hobbies as $hobbies1){
            //echo $hobbies1;
            //$implode  =   implode(',',$hobbies1);
            $sql    =   "INSERT INTO  `userinfo`(`fname`,`lname`,`gender`,`hobbies`,`country`) 
                    values('$fname','$lname','$gender','$hobbies','$country')";

        //}



        //$sql  =   "INSERT INTO  `userinfo`(`fname`,`lname`,`gender`,`hobbies`,`country`) 
        //          values('$fname','$lname','$gender','$hobbies1','$country')";

        $query  =   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if
        ($query){
            echo "<h1>Data inserted .. Happy coding</h1>";
        }else{
            echo "<h1>Please check the problem</h1>";
        }
    }
    //}
    ?>
<form name="registration" method="post" action="">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td><td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required="">Male &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" >Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Hobbies:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="tennis">Tennis &nbsp;<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="cricket">Cricket &nbsp; <br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="dance">Dance7 &nbsp; <br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="sketching">Sketching &nbsp;
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="country">
    <option >----select----</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>Pakistan</option>
    <option>UAE</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register me"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the solution to _your_ problem; and you don't explain how this, applies to, or can solve, OPs question.